# Sodium phenoxide bonding

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, aromatic-compounds, structural-formula

Benzene has O and Na attached. Oxygen with a negative charge and sodium with positive , so they write it as

$\ce{benzene-O- Na+}$

Why couldn't it simply be like oxygen bonded to benzene and sodium there wouldn't be excessive charges.
I think sodium bonds with benzene as well as oxygen ($\ce{benzene-Na-O}$)

Am I right?

Why is it like this? I usually get stuff on my own this seemed really odd for some reason

Comment: Because this is an ionic compound. You must have heard of such in the inorganics course.

Comment: In your second diagram, did you mean to put the sodium between the oxygen and benzene or on the end?

Answer (score 1):

The reason people do this is to highlight the fact that the bond between the oxygen and sodium atom is of a more ionic character than of a covalent character.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking about. If you read it carefully you will see that it is asking about the order in which the atoms are bonded, not the type of bond.

Comment: Actually I see that this might be a mistake on the part of the OP. I will retract my downvote for now until there is clarification.

Comment: Yes, since he refers to it twice, I just assumed it was a mistake since the title is Sodium Phenoxide and he writes the structure correctly once. I have no privileges to do anything so I can't really comment like I'd prefer to do.

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis is a very simple one you know, and its that elements want to be in the lowest state of energy generally by the means of completing a shell or shedding electrons down till they achieve a complete valent shell. 
In this situation its better for sodium to shed a electron and form a ionic bond to achieve the aforementioned than to form a covalent bond with oxygen.